# show following json response inside a table using ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a response as given below

Response :

```
 response: 
{"json":
{"response":
{"servicetype":"",
"functiontype":"",
"statuscode":"0",
"statusmessage":"Success",
"data":[{"graphtype":"piechart",
"xlabel":"state",
"ylabel":"count",
"s1":"contact",
"s2":"User",
"data":["Total Contacts: 1 Users: 20",
[{"x":"Karnataka","s1":"1","s2":"15","lat":"12.9716","long":"77.5946"},
{"x":"New Delhi","s1":"0","s2":"5","lat":"28.6139","long":"77.2090"}]]}]}}}
```

I need to insert table row name , table data name dynamically using ng-repeat.

My table shoud look like.

```
State                  Contact                      User 
 Karnatka                1                           15
 New Delhi               0                           5
```

Comment: From where you getting this response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way to access the dynamic title and data.

Your json response looks quite complex and difficult to access, try to provide simpler json response from server side as much as you can.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = {"json":
{"response":
{"servicetype":"",
"functiontype":"",
"statuscode":"0",
"statusmessage":"Success",
"data":[{"graphtype":"piechart",
"xlabel":"state",
"ylabel":"count",
"s1":"contact",
"s2":"User",
"data":["Total Contacts: 1 Users: 20",
[{"x":"Karnataka","s1":"1","s2":"15","lat":"12.9716","long":"77.5946"},
{"x":"New Delhi","s1":"0","s2":"5","lat":"28.6139","long":"77.2090"}]]}]}}};
  $scope.title = $scope.greeting.json.response.data[0];
  $scope.data = $scope.greeting.json.response.data[0].data[1];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>{{title.xlabel}}</th>
        <th>{{title.s1}}</th>
        <th>{{title.s2}}</th>
      </tr>  
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
        <td>{{row.x}}</td>
        <td>{{row.s1}}</td>
        <td>{{row.s2}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store `response.data` in a variable ex:

```
$scope.graphs = response.data;
```

The view:

```
<div ng-repeat="graph in graphs"> 

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>{{graph.xlabel}}</th>
    <th>{{graph.s2}}</th> 
    <th>{{graph.s1}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="state in graph.data[1]">
    <td>{{ state.x }}</td>
    <td>{{ state.s2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ state.s1 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

[Angular table](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp)